# SSRS For Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 With Pre-Filtering

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

i want to create SSRS with Pre-filtering for Dynamics CRM 2016. But i'm confused how to do it.

Here the query:

```
;with cte as (select dbo.new_troubleticket.new_troubleticketid,  
dbo.new_actiontaken.new_name as [Action Taken], dbo.new_troubleticket.new_rootcauseidname as [Root Cause] from dbo.new_new_troubleticket_new_actiontaken 
INNER JOIN new_troubleticket ON new_new_troubleticket_new_actiontaken.new_troubleticketid = new_troubleticket.new_troubleticketid 
INNER JOIN new_actiontaken ON new_new_troubleticket_new_actiontaken.new_actiontakenid = new_actiontaken.new_actiontakenid)
, cte1 as (Select new_serviceId, dbo.Account.new_CustomerID as [Customer ID],new_accountidname as [Name] from new_service LEFT JOIN Account ON new_service.new_AccountId = Account.AccountId)

Select  dbo.new_troubleticket.new_name as [Ticket ID], dbo.new_troubleticket.new_referalticketname as [Referral Ticket],dbo.new_service.new_Building1 as Link, Dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, getutcdate(), getdate()), new_startdown) As [Down Time], 
Dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, getutcdate(), getdate()), new_startup) As [Up Time], 
dbo.new_service.new_AccountIdName as [Customer Name], cte1.[Customer ID], dbo.new_service.new_name as [Link ID], dbo.new_service.new_Building1 as [Link Name] ,
 dbo.new_troubleticket.new_RootCauseIdName, dbo.new_troubleticket.new_TTActionTaken
,FLOOR((new_troubleticketservice.new_duration*60)/86400) AS HARI
,FLOOR(((new_troubleticketservice.new_duration*60)/3600) - FLOOR((new_troubleticketservice.new_duration*60)/86400) *24) AS JAM 
,FLOOR(((new_troubleticketservice.new_duration*60)/60) - FLOOR((new_troubleticketservice.new_duration*60)/3600) *60) AS MENIT
, new_troubleticketservice.new_duration as [Menit Total]
 from new_troubleticketservice 
 LEFT JOIN new_troubleticket ON new_troubleticketservice.new_TroubleTicketId = new_troubleticket.new_troubleticketId
 LEFT JOIN cte on new_troubleticketservice.new_troubleticketId = cte.new_troubleticketid 
 LEFT JOIN new_service ON new_troubleticketservice.new_ServiceId = new_service.new_serviceId
 LEFT JOIN cte1 on new_troubleticketservice.new_ServiceId = cte1.new_serviceId

  where cte1.[Name] like 'Company a'
```

On the internet, they did it by using this query:

```
Select * from FilteredAccount AS CRMAF_FilteredAccount
```

So, they can run the report based on the selected accounts in the crm view. I want create something similiar like that. But using a little more complex query in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `CRMAF_FilteredEntity` in your SQL statements for the SSRS report, the entities are prefiltered with the entities the user runs the report for. You can use `CRMAF_FilteredEntity` also in other SQL statements like `JOIN` which should yield the desired results.

Comment: i have succesfully run ssrs prefiltering by using sub report. However, im unable to add date parameters